# Add personAccount fields to fieldset

Tags: person-accounts, fieldsets

I have personAccount enabled in my org.
I'm trying to add personAccount fields like PersonMobilePhone to an Account fieldSet but I cannot find these fields in the available fields.
How can I build a personAccount fieldSet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an org with Person Accounts enabled. (Using the Setup web UI), when I add a field set to Account and edit it, Contact fields such as "First Name" and "Mobile" are available to drag and drop into the field set. (The field label is presented not the API name - is that causing the confusion?)

If you are talking about programmatic access, then the API name of standard fields from Contact are prefixed with "Person" and the API name of custom fields from Contact have their "__c" extension changed to "__pc".